# Output missing in a duplicated ML Azure Studio notebook when using multiprocessing - why and how to solve?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, multiprocessing, azure-machine-learning-service

I was trying to optimize my python code using multiprocessing in ML Azure Studio. The code is running fine in the initial notebook and i am getting the O/P as well. I was expecting it to be correct so just wanted to cross-check by running it again in a duplicated notebook. But, although the code is running and going to completion i am not getting any output there. I checked on the following points

1. Cell O/P Settings are not hidden.
2. Execution order is correct.
3. Print statements are not missing.

Why am I  facing this issue?

Attaching a part of my code here:

````
    import multiprocessing as mp
    import time
    new_df_to_pred = pd.DataFrame()

    def process_data(i):

       The function 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
       start_time = time.time()

       # Create a pool of workers
       num_workers = 4
       pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)

       # Submit jobs to the pool
       results = pool.map(process_data, range(0, 40000, 1))

       # Wait for all jobs to finish
       pool.close()
       pool.join()

       # Get the results from the jobs
       new_df_to_pred = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)

       end_time = time.time()

       execution_time = end_time - start_time

       print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a part of my code now.

Answer (score 0):

I created one 2 Notebooks in Azure ML both connected to the same Compute cluster and ran your code with few modifications to get the print output of multiprocessing method successfully,

Refer below:-

**Code:-**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import pandas as pd

new_df_to_pred = pd.DataFrame()

def process_data(i):
    # The function 
    print(f"Processing data for i={i}")
    # Generate some data
    data = pd.DataFrame({'i': [i], 'data': [i * 2]})
    # Return the data
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()

    # Create a pool of workers
    num_workers = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)

    # Submit jobs to the pool
    results = pool.map(process_data, range(0, 40000, 1))
    print("Finished processing data")
    
   # Wait for all jobs to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # Get the results from the jobs
    new_df_to_pred = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)

    end_time = time.time()

    execution_time = end_time - start_time

    print(f"Execution time: {execution_time} seconds")
```

**Output**

**1) multiprocess.ipynb**

[image]

**2) multiprocessduplicate.ipynb**

[image]

***Both the notebooks ran successfully in the same Compute cluster successfully with same code.***